# Webgrid: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Im trying to add in the webgrid column an html image with this code:

```
@model List<LoUCore.Models.Artifact>
@{    
   var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
   List<WebGridColumn> column = new List<WebGridColumn>();
   column.Add(new WebGridColumn { ColumnName = "Filepath", Header = "Sprite",Format = (x => @<text><img src="@x.Filepath"></img></text>) });
 }
@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(column.ToArray()))
```

But im getting the following error:

```
CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `Format = (x => "<text><img src='" + x.Filepath + "'></img></text>")`?

Comment: Nop, this way the <text> razor wont work and it will come as a string not as a html img

Answer (score 3):

You can't use embedded razor strings within the lambda expression, as @Alessandro D'Andra suggests you have to use `x => "<img src='" + someString + "'></img>";` instead.

You might also have to wrap it all in an `MvcHtmlString` to prevent Razor from escaping the string once it is used by the formatter, but I don't know exactly how the formatter works - you have to try it.

I made a small test file to find out exactly what the Razor compiler would do with your code. This is the razor file:

```
@{
    string someString = "somestring";

    Func<object, object> a = x => "<text><img src='" + someString + "'></img></text>";
    Func<object, object> b = x => @<text><img src="@someString"></img></text>);  
}
```

The ASP.NET compiler creates this C# code out of it (only relevant parts included):

```
    string someString = "somestring";

    Func<object, object> a = x => "<text><img src='" + someString + "'></img></text>";
    Func<object, object> b = x => 

            #line default
            #line hidden
item => new System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult(__razor_template_writer => {

BeginContext(__razor_template_writer, "~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", 210, 4, true);

WriteLiteralTo(__razor_template_writer, "<img");

EndContext(__razor_template_writer, "~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", 210, 4, true);

WriteAttributeTo(__razor_template_writer, "src", Tuple.Create(" src=\"", 214), Tuple.Create("\"", 231)

            #line 7 "c:\temp\MvcApplication1\Views\Home\Index.cshtml"
, Tuple.Create(Tuple.Create("", 220), Tuple.Create<System.Object, System.Int32>(someString

            #line default
            #line hidden
, 220), false)
);

BeginContext(__razor_template_writer, "~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", 232, 7, true);

WriteLiteralTo(__razor_template_writer, "></img>");

EndContext(__razor_template_writer, "~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", 232, 7, true);
```

Using the embedded text syntax `@<text>` within the lambda expression creates obviously incorrect C# code. It is not smart enough to make the embedded tags part of the lambda expression, instead it breaks the lambda expression by inserting code to emit the embedded text right away.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible, try this:

```
@model List<LoUCore.Models.Artifact>
@{    
   var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}

@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("Filepath", header: "Sprite", format: x => 
        ((Func<dynamic, object>)(@<text><img src="@x.Filepath"></img></text>)).Invoke(x)
    )
))
```

or, even shorter:

```
@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("Filepath", header: "Sprite", format: @<img src="@item.Filepath"></img>)))
```